# Provide a self signed certificate in eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, certificate

I have a spring-boot service where I process PDF files. I develop on a Windows machine using Eclipse and I'm starting the service within the IDE. 
I created a self signed certificate with PowerShell which results in a .pfx file and I exported it as .cer file. I then used this .pfx to certify a PDF file with Acrobat. Now when I try to process this PDF I get an exception which was to be expected as the service doesn't know anything about this certificate.

What is the easiest way for testing this certified PDF within Eclipse? How do I convert this .cer to a .crt and provide it within Eclipse when I start the service?

EDIT:
I now managed to add this .cer to a keystore:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore cacerts -storepass password -noprompt -alias ThomasSelfSigned -file c:\thomas.cer
```

But how do I tell spring-boot (or probably any other java app to take this keystore when I start the service. All the documentation I found were regarding SSL, but this is not an SSL certificate, but a certificate with which a PDF was protected. And it needs to know it to be able to open it.

For SSL I found these:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword
```

Comment: Your question lacks some details and may have some errors: Please edit it and say describe exactly what you are doing using which program. Furthermore how does Acrobat and the service work together? Are you sure you "certify a PDF file with Acrobat" (signing would make more sense).

Comment: @Robert Certifying and Signing are two different things. Usually a company or a government certifies their PDF so the customer/citizen can be sure of the validity of this PDF. Then the customer can sign this PDF (usually a form) with his digital signature and the provider has a legal binding document with both a certificate from itself (would be invalid if the PDF was changed beside filling form fields) and has a signature from the other party.

Comment: The Java `keyStore` properties are for certificates that have a private key. You are searching for the `trustStore`.